# Community♦ Gifted questions

Tags: discussion, questions, community-user

On [Community♦](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)'s page if says and I quote :

{Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention}

What algorithm is used for this **random** throws of questions ? Does it bring up useful questions only ? How ?

Comment: I think there is some minimum score below which questions are not poked. Aside from that I believe it is random. It is certainly the case that it dredges up some real stinkers from time to time.

Comment: I hate to interrupt the *random* discussion. [Here's a related one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160711/205334). Wait, am I in the right place? We're in the meta, right? :D